# How to implement this App server

Tags: c#, security, vmware

Hello all i have a server and some clients

Scenario is that every client is an exe and when it opens it checks for server if server is there and responding client can do its work other wise that app will be closed on the other hand server also verifies the number of maximum allowed clients for example it will allow only 5 users to connect 
i have to deploy this at development side but my concerns are that anyone can open multiple servers and can point client to that server , so i am allowing only one instance of a server on a specific pc by using its hdd serial number so is it safe to do this:? i think it can be easily broken by vmware and anyone can run multiple instances of my server on different pc's by using vmware please clarify me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I understand, yes people can clone your server and it is possible even to spoof hard drive serial number.

You can alternatively host your server in cloud and provide services to your client. 
You may also encrypt the harddrive and then it can't be used in another computer.
In case you are using a vm for the server, Use Truecript to wrap everything in a container.Make sure to only open the container when you need it, and close it when you're done.

Comment: i am marking this answer coz i am already encrypting every thing and its not easy to decrypt it.and i have a choice of cloud but my client is not willing for cloud because of some security headaches